# How to create a window of arbitrary size in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Using [prev()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/prevfunction) function I can access previous rows individually.

```
mytable
| sort by Time asc
| extend mx = max_of(prev(Value, 1), prev(Value, 2), prev(Value, 3))
```

How to define a window to aggregate over in more generic way? Say I need maximum of 100 values in previous rows. How to write a query that does not require repeating `prev()` 100 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be achieved by combining [scan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scan-operator) and [series_stats_dynamic()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/series-stats-dynamicfunction).

`scan` is used to create an array of last x values, per record.
`series_stats_dynamic()` is used to get the max value of each array.

```
// Data sample generation. Not part of the solution
let mytable = materialize(range i from 1 to 15 step 1 | extend Time = ago(1d*rand()),  Value = toint(rand(100)));
// Solution starts here
let window_size = 3; // >1
mytable
|   order by Time asc
|   scan declare (last_x_vals:dynamic) 
    with 
    (
        step s1 : true => last_x_vals = array_concat(array_slice(s1.last_x_vals, -window_size + 1, -1), pack_array(Value));
    )
|   extend toint(series_stats_dynamic(last_x_vals).max)
```

| i | Time | Value | last_x_vals | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 2022-06-10T11:25:49.9321294Z | 45 | [45] | 45 |
| 14 | 2022-06-10T11:54:13.3729674Z | 82 | [45,82] | 82 |
| 2 | 2022-06-10T13:25:40.9832745Z | 44 | [45,82,44] | 82 |
| 1 | 2022-06-10T17:38:28.3230397Z | 24 | [82,44,24] | 82 |
| 7 | 2022-06-10T18:29:33.926463Z | 17 | [44,24,17] | 44 |
| 15 | 2022-06-10T19:54:33.8253844Z | 9 | [24,17,9] | 24 |
| 3 | 2022-06-10T20:17:46.1347592Z | 43 | [17,9,43] | 43 |
| 12 | 2022-06-11T00:02:55.5315197Z | 94 | [9,43,94] | 94 |
| 9 | 2022-06-11T00:11:18.5924511Z | 61 | [43,94,61] | 94 |
| 11 | 2022-06-11T00:39:40.6858444Z | 38 | [94,61,38] | 94 |
| 4 | 2022-06-11T03:54:59.418534Z | 84 | [61,38,84] | 84 |
| 10 | 2022-06-11T05:55:38.2904242Z | 6 | [38,84,6] | 84 |
| 6 | 2022-06-11T07:25:43.3977923Z | 36 | [84,6,36] | 84 |
| 13 | 2022-06-11T09:36:08.7904844Z | 28 | [6,36,28] | 36 |
| 8 | 2022-06-11T09:51:45.2225391Z | 73 | [36,28,73] | 73 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA01Ry07DMBC8R8o/zNGG0tRCXFrRE2cuIK7RNllaC8eO7C1tUD8e53GoL/Y+ZndmXFV4IyEk6nrHOLLnSGKDX+M9CHqKgvANOTFScOexUhaOBd0gdMiIV3QkHC05+8cqkj8yLL5j6GAgAeYFSbjPwQ18FfYtPm034ugYlGkfMqRVWq+AL3LnsSDBelFT3mw2WutdWVQVPpb9eV5mlXDiyDOXi/VtuNQpM8jw5x1y996UxcKxLG4AQmw54jDM6yk1czo15NFy4ygylKMk9bX+JZe27eCps41GWeS+vEROy1PN13gmbclgC4kj+T3uRowiY6ShboJvSNQcJGcbVsms7zpXeLoX8QiTMyab0lPzU084NdkzmTEu1jP9xdLZspT/gVOd/ZFUL/TvJel1R1f9Dzc2c5zzAQAA)

Comment: See improved answer

Comment: Strangely it fails with the following error in my cluster: "Semantic error: scan step s1: the expression in the assignment of last_x_vals is not supported by EngineV3 - scalar function 'array_slice' is not supported". At the same time the function itself is available in queries like `print arr=dynamic([1,2,3]) | extend sliced=array_slice(arr, 1, 2)`.

Comment: There are bunch of functions that does not work in the context of `scan`. Could you share `.show cluster | distinct ProductVersion`?

Comment: 2022.05.30.0632-GA-06e712d1b-WeeklyProdPubExt

Comment: My version is from 2022.06.09. In what egion is your cluster deployed?

Comment: It is Central US. Do you mean this might be a brand-new feature implemented in last two weeks?

Comment: Exactly. I'll check with the team.