# How to create a rolling time window to find max value in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

Imagine a data set with some time gaps between the records:

```
datatable(t:datetime , v: int)
[
    datetime(2022-01-01 07:00), 3,
    datetime(2022-01-01 07:15), 2,
    datetime(2022-01-01 07:30), 4,
    datetime(2022-01-01 07:45), 1,
    datetime(2022-01-01 08:00), 5,
    // GAP!
    datetime(2022-01-01 10:15), 8,
    datetime(2022-01-01 10:30), 3,
    datetime(2022-01-01 10:45), 2,
    // ALSO GAP!
    datetime(2022-01-01 11:30), 1,
]
```

I'm trying to find a max value for each record within previous hour, excluding the current iteration hour.
To visualize it, I want to achieve something like that:

| t | v | prev_hr | max_v |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 07:00 | 3 | 2022-01-01 06:00 | null |
| 2022-01-01 07:15 | 2 | 2022-01-01 06:15 | 3 |
| 2022-01-01 07:30 | 4 | 2022-01-01 06:30 | 3 |
| 2022-01-01 07:45 | 1 | 2022-01-01 06:45 | 4 |
| 2022-01-01 08:00 | 5 | 2022-01-01 07:00 | 4 |
| 2022-01-01 10:15 | 8 | 2022-01-01 09:15 | null |
| 2022-01-01 10:30 | 3 | 2022-01-01 09:30 | 8 |
| 2022-01-01 10:45 | 2 | 2022-01-01 09:45 | 8 |
| 2022-01-01 11:30 | 1 | 2022-01-01 10:30 | 3 |

I've tried modifying the approach suggested in [How to create a window of arbitrary size in Kusto?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72580497/how-to-create-a-window-of-arbitrary-size-in-kusto) (so using [scan()](https://www.stackoverflow.com/) operator) but had problems applying it to the above. Also, I feel like something like [time_window_rolling_avg_fl()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/functions-library/time-window-rolling-avg-fl?tabs=adhoc) might be useful here, but it seems complex for a simple use-case like above.

I feel like what I want to achieve is relatively simple and obvious, but I am just missing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the suggestion below. Inspired by [aggregations over a sliding window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/samples?pivots=azuredataexplorer#perform-aggregations-over-a-sliding-window).

```
datatable(t:datetime , v: int)
[
    datetime(2022-01-01 07:00), 3,
    datetime(2022-01-01 07:15), 2,
    datetime(2022-01-01 07:30), 4,
    datetime(2022-01-01 07:45), 1,
    datetime(2022-01-01 08:00), 5,
    // GAP!
    datetime(2022-01-01 10:15), 8,
    datetime(2022-01-01 10:30), 3,
    datetime(2022-01-01 10:45), 2,
    // ALSO GAP!
    datetime(2022-01-01 11:30), 1,
]
| extend bin_t = bin(t, 1m)
| extend _range = range(bin_t, bin_t+1h, 1m)
| mv-expand _range to typeof(datetime)
| as T | join kind=inner T on $left.bin_t == $right._range
| project t, t1, v, v1
| summarize max_v = maxif(v1, t1 < t) by t, v
| project t, v, prev_h = t-1h, max_v
```

| t | v | prev_h | max_v |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 07:00:00.0000000 | 3 | 2022-01-01 06:00:00.0000000 |  |
| 2022-01-01 07:15:00.0000000 | 2 | 2022-01-01 06:15:00.0000000 | 3 |
| 2022-01-01 07:30:00.0000000 | 4 | 2022-01-01 06:30:00.0000000 | 3 |
| 2022-01-01 07:45:00.0000000 | 1 | 2022-01-01 06:45:00.0000000 | 4 |
| 2022-01-01 08:00:00.0000000 | 5 | 2022-01-01 07:00:00.0000000 | 4 |
| 2022-01-01 10:15:00.0000000 | 8 | 2022-01-01 09:15:00.0000000 |  |
| 2022-01-01 10:30:00.0000000 | 3 | 2022-01-01 09:30:00.0000000 | 8 |
| 2022-01-01 10:45:00.0000000 | 2 | 2022-01-01 09:45:00.0000000 | 8 |
| 2022-01-01 11:30:00.0000000 | 1 | 2022-01-01 10:30:00.0000000 | 3 |

Comment: Thank you for suggesting this. It seems to solve the issue I had, while the performance is still within reasonable boundaries, even for larger data sets.

Comment: In real-life scenarios, when some complex calculation might be used instead of `datatable()` literal, I think there a benefit in materializing the augmented table before joining it to itself.

Comment: I assume binning was added to address the case when times are not "round". In such a case, an additional condition must be added to `maxif()`: `and t - t1 <= 1h`, to work properly with a case like "2022-01-01 08:00:01" on the fifth line.

Answer (score 1):

Another option, based on cross join, which mean disastrous performance for large data sets.

```
let MyTable = datatable(t:datetime , v: int)
[
    datetime(2022-01-01 07:00), 3,
    datetime(2022-01-01 07:15), 2,
    datetime(2022-01-01 07:30), 4,
    datetime(2022-01-01 07:45), 1,
    datetime(2022-01-01 08:00), 5,
    // GAP!
    datetime(2022-01-01 10:15), 8,
    datetime(2022-01-01 10:30), 3,
    datetime(2022-01-01 10:45), 2,
    // ALSO GAP!
    datetime(2022-01-01 11:30), 1,
]
| extend dummy = 1;
MyTable
| join kind=inner MyTable on dummy
| where t - t1 between (0h .. 1h)
| summarize x = maxif(v1, t1 != t) by t, v
```

| t | v | x |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01T07:00:00Z | 3 |  |
| 2022-01-01T07:15:00Z | 2 | 3 |
| 2022-01-01T07:30:00Z | 4 | 3 |
| 2022-01-01T07:45:00Z | 1 | 4 |
| 2022-01-01T08:00:00Z | 5 | 4 |
| 2022-01-01T10:15:00Z | 8 |  |
| 2022-01-01T10:30:00Z | 3 | 8 |
| 2022-01-01T10:45:00Z | 2 | 8 |
| 2022-01-01T11:30:00Z | 1 | 3 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA4WRQUvDQBCF7/kVr7cE0nYnSWlJyaEnL4qC3sRDQkayttlCHNtE/PFOWBUvTXf2MDAfb+bxDiy4G57K6sAoUJeipX0oufYstmXEOOWwTqLgOYC+30GYmCSZG9IPs86NiWKk8RRCK0WSSSQdVbJJJBtVaALZ+FtWHlkucbN7mF3Eyfi7NpcVFUmvuFMk++dOl+5uH++vbCYvq15egi9wL+xq1B9tO2gWtA1+gtHZ29E67K2rC+scd3+RHZ3nFTk33DEEcwihYjkzO4SmwWIBaiIl3pUsO/vJ6FW/LXv7Gp4oHvlZAYlQDRBN+xue00JRFAIAAA==)

Comment: Thank you for the alternative approach!

Answer (score 1):

Thinking about possible optimizations of @yifats's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74449319/947012), I am coming to the idea that the `range()` extension must provide only the minimum amount of items, just to create a "bridge" linking the report row with every aggregated row, and that evaluates to range step of the same size as the aggregation window.

```
let input = datatable(t:datetime , v: int)
[
    datetime(2022-01-01 07:00), 3,
    datetime(2022-01-01 07:15), 2,
    datetime(2022-01-01 07:30), 4,
    datetime(2022-01-01 07:45), 1,
    datetime(2022-01-01 08:00), 5,
    // GAP!
    datetime(2022-01-01 10:15), 8,
    datetime(2022-01-01 10:30), 3,
    datetime(2022-01-01 10:45), 2,
    // ALSO GAP!
    datetime(2022-01-01 11:30), 1,
];
let window = 1h;
input
| extend bin_t = bin(t, window)
| extend _range = range(bin_t, bin_t + window, window)
| mv-expand _range to typeof(datetime)
| as T
| join kind=inner T on $left.bin_t == $right._range
| summarize max_v = maxif(v1, t1 < t and t - t1 <= 1h) by t, v
```

This variant produces only 64 records after joining, as opposed to @yifats's variant giving 1464 records. Generally, the maximum number of product records per an input row equals [number of items in `range` output] * [number of records in the preceding time window, including the current record], thus the product of joining 5th input row gives output of 61 * 5 = 305 rows with 1min range step, whereas my variant above gives only 2 * 5 = 10 rows. I think this one will be more performant and memory-efficient.